# Rails Asset Pipeline / Sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've switched to using the asset pipeline recently. Everything is working well and I can precompile for production with no problems.

The trouble I'm having is in my development environment I want changes I make to take affect without having to precompile. I couldn't find clear instructions on how to see my latest CSS changes immediately locally. As an example, should I be using something like this in addition to my application.css.scss' @import statements?

```
//= depends_on reset
//= depends_on typography

@import "reset.css.scss"
@import "typography.css.scss"
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: David, my modifications take effect in development. Did you tried to remove your precompiled assets in the public folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't run `rake assets:precompile` locally if you want to see local changes appear. I suspect this is what you're doing, so that's why local changes are not appearing. Clear `public/assets` and then it will start to serve assets from the right directories, compiling them if they change and then serving.

Comment: This did the trick for me. I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks!

Comment: So will `rm -rf public/assets`.